# C# wuapilib - Windows Updates (Console App) failure - invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, exception, casting, installation

**Environment:**

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1

C# -- .NET 4.0

**Problem:**
Everything works fine, except the installation.

After much thought and research, **I suspect that the problem is an attempted cast from  --  “COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'WUApiLib.UpdateInstaller'.”** As can be seen in the code, the IID and type have been set but the values of the parameters are suspect.  The Following is the runtime error report:

> System.InvalidCastException was caught.  Message=Specified cast is not
>   valid.   Source=PROGRAM_NAME   StackTrace:
>          at WUApiLib.IUpdateInstaller.Install()
>          at PROGRAM_NAME.WindowsUpdates.InstallUpdates(UpdateCollection updatesToInstall)  in %PATH%\visual studio 2010\Projects\ … 
>   InnerException:

**Request:**

After many hours of research and study, any help to resolve the problem of installing the updates would be greatly appreciated.  Please see the following code snippets.

**Program attempts the following:**

-- Windows update services are enabled (No problems)

-- That the host machine needs to be updated:  (No problems)

-- Downloads the updates:  (No problems)

```
public static UpdateCollection DownloadUpdates()
{
    // Returns UpdateCollection object. 
}
```

-- Attempts to install the updates.  (Exception:  Specified cast is not valid.)

```
public static void InstallUpdates(UpdateCollection updatesToInstall)
{

     IUpdateInstaller updateInstaller;
     Console.WriteLine("Creating UpdateInstasller...");

    //Type itype = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", true);
    //Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", "127.0.0.1")
    Type itype = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Installer", true);

    updateInstaller = (UpdateInstaller)Activator.CreateInstance(itype);
    updateInstaller.Updates = updatesToInstall;
    updateInstaller.ClientApplicationID = "{3442D4FE-224D-4CEE-98CF-30E0C4D229E6}"; //    Unsure of IID
    IInstallationResult installationResult;
    Console.WriteLine("Creating UpdateInstallationResult...");
    updateInstaller.IsForced = true;

    if (updateInstaller.IsBusy == false)
    {
       try
       {
          installationResult = updateInstaller.Install(); // ***Bad Cast exception here.***
          if (updatesToInstall.Count > 0)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < updatesToInstall.Count; i++)
              {
               if (installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).HResult == 0)
                         Console.WriteLine("Installed : " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                    else
                         Console.WriteLine("Failed : " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);

                    // Is Reboot Required?
                    if (installationResult.RebootRequired == true)
                        Console.WriteLine("Reboot is required for one of more updates.");
               } // end for
          } // end if 
        } // end try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Error:: " + e.Message + "\n");
        }

    } // end if
} // end method
```

Comment: Well, look like i'll have to figure this one out for myself.  That's usually the way it works.  Once I have the solution, I'll post up.

Comment: FYI: I finally just completely re-wrote the code in one method.  Once I did that, everything worked fine.